# Systemd service is unable to resolve host (temporary failure in name resolution), but the root user is able to

Tags: systemd, network-interface, systemd-resolved

I have a systemd service that runs a script that checks my wireguard connection. The service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check the wg status and restart it if necessary
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/checkwg.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script `checkwg.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wgout=$(wg show)

if [[ ! -n $wgout  ]] # check to see if there is an active wg connection
then
        echo "wg appears down, reactivating..."
        wg-quick up myvpn # This line throws "Temporary failure in name resolution"
else
        echo "wg is up"
fi
```

There's an if statement that checks if wg is up. If it's not up then it runs `wg-quick up myvpn`.

The script works when I run it as root (I'm using Dietpi so there is only one user, root). Here is the output:

```
./checkwg.sh
wg appears down, reactivating...
[#] ip link add myvpn type wireguard
[#] wg setconf myvpn /dev/fd/63
[#] ip address add 10.0.4.54 dev myvpn
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev myvpn
[#] ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 dev myvpn
[#] wg set myvpn fwmark 51820
```

But when I try to run `checkwg.service` (by running `systemctl restart checkwg`), it gives me:

```
systemctl restart checkwg
journalctl -fu checkwg.service
May 17 10:22:30 camera systemd[1]: Started Check the wg status and restart it if necessary.
May 17 10:22:30 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: wg appears down, reactivating...
May 17 10:22:31 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: [#] ip link add myvpn type wireguard
May 17 10:22:31 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: [#] wg setconf myvpn /dev/fd/63
May 17 10:22:31 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: Temporary failure in name resolution: `myvpn.myhost.com:5555'. Trying again in 1.50 seconds...
May 17 10:22:32 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: Temporary failure in name resolution: `myvpn.myhost.com:5555'. Trying again in 2.25 seconds...
May 17 10:22:34 camera checkwg.sh[23181]: Temporary failure in name resolution: `myvpn.myhost.com:5555'. Trying again in 3.38 seconds...
```

Why is systemd unable to resolve my host but the root user is able to?
I am fairly confident this is not a wireguard issue, because when i replace `wg-quick up myvpn` with `ping google.com` it throws the same error: `Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: Hard to say anything without knowing what wg-quick does. One detail: The domain to be resolved is literally "myvpn.myhost.com:5555". I am sure there is no domain named like this; I am not even sure if a domain name can have a colon. Something makes wg-quick use an incorrect domain name.

Comment: "DNS names can contain only alphabetical characters (A-Z), numeric characters (0-9), the minus sign (-), and the period (.)" (from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou :)).

Comment: @berndbausch, You're right, I changed the actual name to `myvpn` for privacy, but as I said in the question, if I replace `wg-quick up myvpn` with `ping google.com` I get the exact same error.

Comment: Oops, I need to brush up on my reading skills. I would replace the ping with `dig myvpn.myhost.com` to gather more info, or even go nuclear and run `tcpdump -i any udp port 53` to see what's going on behind the scene.

Comment: Great idea!
I threw in a `dig myvpn.myhost.com > /home/digout` line above the `ping google.com` and this is what I got:
`; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Raspbian <<>> myvpn.myhost.com

;; global options: +cmd


;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: This is puzzling, but the unwavering troubleshooter's next step is figuring out what makes wg-quick or the systemd service not recognize your DNS resolution config. Perhaps tcpdump is really the way to go.

Comment: Welp, running `tcpdump -A > tcpdump &` followed by `systemctl restart checkwg` yields a blank `tcpdump` file. But of course when I run `ping google.com` from my shell, the `tcpdump` file gets filled with the standard networking output. I really am stumped with this one

Comment: `tcpdump -A` selects the most likely NIC. Use `tcpdump -i any port 53` to listen on all interfaces including loopback, and to only show DNS traffic. Also review your DNS config - probably the usual weird config based on `systemd-resolved` listening on localhost:53 that is now widely deployed. I wonder `systemd-resolved` log messages reveal something.

Comment: I was facing this issue and it turns out SELinux was blocking it from resolving DNS (but only in a system service (root) and not when directly running wireguard as root user) Which is weird cause Ive never seen this on any of my other machines (also running wireguard with wg-quick with selinux set to enforcing)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue after a system upgrade (to Fedora 38).
It was fixed by adding:

```
LoadCredential=network.dns
```

under the `[Service]` section.

Cheers, Jan.

Comment: It would be interesting to know _why_ this fixed your issue and whether it would also fix the issue presented in the question.